# c++のatof(文字列/浮動小数点数)について

Tags: c++

プログラミング初心者です。 
char str [] = "100.00"; double value; という左記の配列において、
strの文字列をdoubleに変換し、その結果をvalueに格納する文を作成したいです。

以下のコードを作成してデバッグしてみたのですが、何も起こりませんでした。
正しく格納されたという認識でよろしいでしょうか。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
　　　　
int main()
{
    char str[] = "100.00";
    double value;
    value = atof(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

何もおこらないのは、代入しただけで、何もしていないからです。代入が成功したか確認するために、結果を表示してみましょう。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[] = "100.00";
    double value;
    value = atof(str);
    cout << value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`cout << value << endl;` というのが表示の処理です。

余談ですが、ごく一部のC++プログラマの間では `cout` というのは人気がありません。
`cout` はC++における標準的な表示方法なので、初学者が使う分には問題はありません。
宗教上の理由（？）により `cout` を積極的に使う人と、避ける人がいます。
私は `cout` を使わない派なので、代わりに `printf` 関数を使います。
`printf("%f\n", value);` と書いても、値を表示することができます。
これは古くからあるC言語のやり方で、どちらが良いかは賛否あり、
性能とか、安全性とか、読みやすさとか、単なる好みとか、
宗教論争にさえなります。

Comment: 詳細なご説明ありがとうございます！
printf関数につきましてもご教示頂きありがとうございます。どちらも使いこなせるようがんばります！